# PostgreSQL print result from query with empty lines

Tags: postgresql

I write this query but the result is full with empty lines. How to print a result without empty lines. I will attach a screen shot of the result.

[image]

```
SELECT user_data.alternative_mail
FROM user_data
JOIN users_map
ON users_map.user_id = user_data.user_id
WHERE users_map.service_id = 1 AND 
    users_map.service_user_id = 0 AND
    user_data.alternative_mail NOT LIKE '%@abv.bg'
```

Answer (score 1):

You could check if email `IS NOT NULL` and empty string:

```
SELECT user_data.alternative_mail
FROM user_data
JOIN users_map
  ON users_map.user_id = user_data.user_id
WHERE users_map.service_id = 1 
  AND users_map.service_user_id = 0 
  AND user_data.alternative_mail NOT LIKE '%@abv.bg'
  AND user_data.alternative_mail IS NOT NULL 
  AND user_data.alternative_mail <> '';
```